# How to get killing tests against each mutant or a complete killing matrix with PIT1.3.0?

Tags: java, testing, pitest

I am using jdk7 on defects4j 1.0 and I need to use PITest to mutate the code.

As is shown in the releases of pit, https://github.com/hcoles/pitest/releases?page=5
pit1.4+ no longer supports jdk7 so I have to choose pit1.3.2 to do my research.

But I find that pit stops analyzing each mutant as soon as there is a test case that kills it, which is mentioned here,
[Automatically recognize which mutants killed by which test cases in Pitest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864954/automatically-recognize-which-mutants-killed-by-which-test-cases-in-pitest/44875465#44875465)

Is there some actionable way to get a complete killing matrix, or get all tests that kill each mutant, while still using pit 1.3.X which is compatible with jdk7?

Or Is there a way to let pit only pick a test case(method level) to execute?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Full matrix mode was introduced in pitest 1.5.2, enabled with the `fullMutationMatrix` parameter. It is an only partially supported feature, other pitest features are not guaranteed to work if it is enabled.

You would need to back port it to 1.3.2 if you wish to run on Java 7.

Considerably less effort would be just to use the latest version of pitest and Java 8. The majority of Java 7 codebases will compile and test without issue. You will usually only encounter problems if they use a bytecode manipulation library that does not recognise the more modern Java version.

Comment: Thank you, Herry.
The reason why I use jdk7 is that some initially passing tests on d4j1.0 would fail when I switched to jdk8, which would influence the research result. Details about the dataset can be found here, https://github.com/rjust/defects4j/tree/v1.0.0. I think mutation testing with pit on d4j1.0 and jdk7 should be somewhat of a common practice many years ago, say 2015. Back then what was the possible solution? Currently, my solution is to replace the .class file of each mutant and run the test suite many times to get a full killing matrix.

Comment: The soloution most researchers used was to hack pitest to produce a matrix.